# VBS selecting rows

Tags: sql, vbscript

How do I select a particular row from sql table. Example if value of variable is 2, then select 2nd row from table?

Is there any function in VBS to determine how many rows are in the table?

Comment: 1. Which DBMS? 2. What is the sort criteria to identify the 2nd row?

Comment: 1.SQL 2008 2.The sort criteria is by "id" column, but i want to select a row independent of "id" column

Comment: when you say independent, do you mean "without specifying filter on id column"?

Comment: values in id column are like 1,3,5,8,9 so i can't select row based on value of an id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I select a particular row from sql table. Example if value of variable is 2, then select 2nd row from table?

You can execute the following SQL, that uses the [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) SQL Server function to always get the second row, for example, by ordering the records by `id` column in `DESC` order:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) 'RowRank' FROM MyTable 
) AS A
WHERE RowRank = 2
```

> Is there any function in VBS to determine how many rows are in the table?

I am not sure if VBS has out-of-the-box function to get the number of rows in a table, but you can use a simple SQL query to find that out:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
```

This would return a value, but the query above that is selecting the second row would return a list of column values, as present in the table.

Comment: can you update your question with the code snippet that is throwing this error?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable, how do i save these value into variable?